# What is the equivalent `nom` parser/combinator for the pattern /.*foobar/

Tags: regex, rust, nom

I've been reading through [the documentation](https://docs.rs/nom/6.2.1/nom) for `nom` 6.2.1 and I'm trying to construct a parser which will match any number of characters (including zero) followed by the word foobar: `/.*foobar/`.

`nom::bytes::complete::take_until("foobar")` almost does what I want, but it will not consume `foobar` itself, so I'd have to instead do:

```rust
use nom::bytes::complete::{tag, take_until};
use nom::combinator::value;
use nom::sequence::tuple;
use nom::IResult;

// This method does what I want, but is verbose because foobar is repeated
fn arbitrary_and_then_foobar(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, ()> {
    value((), tuple((take_until("foobar"), tag("foobar"))))(s)
}
```

I tend to think in terms of the traditional regular expression syntax and then have to map that to the available constructs that `nom` provides. I'm getting better at noticing scenarios where the `nom` constructs fit better, but is there a regex-to-nom cheatsheet?

Comment: Many languages use `//` to mark a regex literal in source code. Since Rust does not, your phrasing is potentially more unclear than it needs to be — do you want to match the literal characters / string `/`?

Comment: https://docs.rs/nom/6.2.1/nom/sequence/fn.terminated.html ?

Comment: @Shepmaster, can you elaborate? I don't have anything specific to capture as the first argument, other than it not matching `foobar`.

Comment: Nom does have a `regexp` feature that lets you parse with regular expressions if you can't come up with a better solution.

Comment: I do not speak regex, mainly because regex is a mess, so please describe what you want with word or example.